# Extract only dates for first Day of Month from a daily Date Dimension Table without nesting

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, date, group-by

I am using `SQL Server 2014` and I have the following `T-SQL` query which retrieves the dates of the first day of each month (based on my filters) from a `Date Dimension` Table:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, [date]), 0) AS [Date2]
    FROM DateDimension
    WHERE [date] BETWEEN '2018-07-01' AND '2019-06-01'
) x
GROUP BY x.[Date2]
```

The output is as follows:

```
Date2
2018-07-01 00:00:00.000
2018-08-01 00:00:00.000
2018-09-01 00:00:00.000
2018-10-01 00:00:00.000
2018-11-01 00:00:00.000
2018-12-01 00:00:00.000
2019-01-01 00:00:00.000
2019-02-01 00:00:00.000
2019-03-01 00:00:00.000
2019-04-01 00:00:00.000
2019-05-01 00:00:00.000
2019-06-01 00:00:00.000
```

I have used a nested query to achieve this. My question is whether I can achieve the same result without using the nested query. My `Date Dimension` table is a table with daily dates.

Comment: Might be I get something wrong, but the code you provide doesn't make much sense for me... Just `WHERE DAY([date])=1`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just repeat the date calculation part inside `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, [date]), 0) AS [Date2]
FROM DateDimension
WHERE [date] between '2018-07-01' and '2019-06-01'
GROUP BY DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, [date]), 0)
```

PS: this:

```
DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, [date]), 0)
```

could be written as:

```
DATEADD(DAY, 1, EOMONTH([date], -1))
```

Answer (score 1):

Can't we just write this with a distinct,

```
SELECT DISTINCT DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, [date]), 0) AS [Date2]
FROM DateDimension
where [date] between '2018-07-01' and '2019-06-01'
```